# Get last login time to VM with pyvmomi

Tags: virtual-machine, pyvmomi

I’m trying to get the last time user logged in to each one of the VM’s we have and the user name using pyvmomi without login to each one of the VM to get this info, I'm not looking for a specific user just the last one.
I searched the github and VMware API and SDK Documentation and didn’t find a way to do that so I don’t have any code I can share.
Any ideas ?

Comment: were you able to get last login information?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [execute_program_in_vm](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/execute_program_in_vm.py) script that's in Pyvmomi Community Samples at Github.

Just adapt the code to let you look into a group of VMs (by folder or name) instead of 1 VM by IP. You'll also depend on having VMware tools installed in your VMs, cause this is a requirement.

You should be able to run a Powershell script (in case of Windows VMs) or bash to get what you want.

```
pm = content.guestOperationsManager.processManager    
ps = vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(
    programPath=<path_to_program>,
    arguments=<args.program_arguments>
    )
res = pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, ps)
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928104/what-is-the-pyvmomi-equivalent-of-invoke-vmscript-in-powercli) StackOverflow question as well, to create your script in VM first. Not an easy task!